Add a line break in a mermaid quadrant chart
Hi do I break the lines on quadrant labels in a quadrantChart using Mermaid?
Thank you!
%%{init: {"quadrantChart": {"htmlLabels": false}} }%%
quadrantChart 
  title Test
    x-axis state --> society
      y-axis individual --> collective
        quadrant-2 Institutionalist<br/>Approaches
        quadrant-3 State<br/>Approaches
        quadrant-4 Political Psychology<br/>Political Behaviour
        quadrant-1 Political Economy<br/>Political Sociology

